# Responsiveness doesn't work on "device mode" google chrome dev tools

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

I'm creating a website that is responsive when I resize the window.  None of the responsiveness works when I toggle device mode even though I'm going below the breakpoints.  I don't understand why it works in the normal browser when I trigger the break points but not in device mode.  What am I doing wrong?

```
// style.css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
@media (max-width: 75em) {
    html {
        font-size: 56.25%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 56.25em) {
    html {
        font-size: 50%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 112.5em) {
    html {
        font-size: 75%;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake you made was by not adding `only screen and`. Try doing:

`@media only screen and (max-width: ...) {}`

Comment: That didn't fix the issue.  
The problem originally was I needed to add in "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />" and then it started working but now it stopped being responsive again and I can't understand why.